# Texmaker home/end keys on Mac OS X

Tags: texmaker, mac

In Mac OS X, the home/end keys per default throw you at the beginning/end of the document instead of the beginning/end line. I have changed my system key bindings to get the latter, "usual" (Windows- and Linux-like) behavior.

However, texmaker seems to ignore this setting. It is horribly distracting when I have to search for my editing position in a longer text each time after unconsciously hitting the end key.

I did not find these commands in the "configure texmaker" dialog. Is there a way to persuade texmaker to respect the system key bindings, or can I modify the setting in texmaker individually?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use free tool called Karabiner
https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/

I have tested it in TexMaker on OSX / Mac using PC keyboard

Map settings like in screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, works great!  Karabiner is a great thing, generally works much better than the key bindings also for other apps.

Comment: The screenshot is out of date, but the concept works.  For the version of Karabiner-Elements I downloaded yesterday, I imported the PC-style shortcuts on the Complex Modifications tab, then enabled all of the PC-style shortcuts.  (I tried to enable some of them one at a time, but to no avail.)  Note that I have two separate profiles in Karabiner - one for TexMaker and one the default as the PC-style shortcuts do weird things in some other apps.

Answer (score 3):

The other answer is outdated. You indeed use can use install free tool https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/.

Start **Karabiner-Elements**. Then, go to **Complex modifications**. Click **+Add Rule**, and Import more rules from the Internet. It will open a browser window. Look for *Personal PC-Style Shortcuts (@Bave Lee)* and download those. This will add some settings, and you will want to enable **PC-Style Home/End**.

That did it for me immediately, no need to restart the system.